Ruby Can't Open Large CSV File on an M3 MBPro But Can on a Windows Desktop PC with similar hardware
I'm attempting to open a large CSV file with the SmarterCSV rails gem but on my M3 Pro with 32 Gigs Ram it just hangs and fails to open the file (even if using chunks) when running:
SmarterCSV.process(open("the_file.csv"), {chunk_size: 10000, convert_values_to_numeric: false})

If I run this on my PC and open in rails (using WSL2) it opens in seconds without even using chunks...  Any idea on what could be the bottleneck here?  Any help identifying the bottleneck would be greatly appreciated.
Update -- I can process it in very small batches on the M3Pro so it's at least working (and will complete the rake task at nearly the same time overall as the PC) but I'm surprised the machine isn't capable of processing the entire file at once like my PC can without batching... Seems odd to me.

A bit of a side note but you don't need to use Kernel#open (just pass the file name) and in fact doing so is considered  potentially harmful as it introduces a risk of remote code execution. If you do need to open a file stream use the File class. Also how much ram your system has is irrelevant if the process is capped.
